# How do I prevent Microsoft Security Essentials from warning me about recent scans?

Tags: windows-7, ms-security-essentials

I use my computer daily, and scan at the start of each month. Though perhaps it's foolish of me to do so, I am confident enough in my immediate recognition of my computers' behaviour, and the automatic new file scanning of MSE, that I do not care for scanning every other day as the program seems to think is wise.

It's extremely distracting seeing the little orange "at risk" icon in the corner of my screen, as I cannot tell at a glance if something is *actually* wrong, like if a part of the program disables itself, or if it's just wanting me to run a scan again.

I want to keep the icon there, I purely want to disable MSE checking for whether I've run a recent scan.

Comment: Not sure if you keep your computer is turned on overnight and such but could you schedule a quick scan once a week at 2am?